# AWS : Is there a way to pause/unpause traffic to Elastic LoadBalancers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Here's the scenario -

*We're spinning up a few Instances via Cloudformation Autoscaling group which attaches instances to an Elastic Load Balancer using CloudFormation. The intent is, before the ELB starts serving traffic to these instances, we want to perform a few curl tests and once those look good - enable traffic flow to the instances via ELB.*

Question : Is there a way to prevent the Elastic LoadBalancer to NOT send traffic to the instances until we allow it?

If not - is there a way to remove the "Attached Instances" to ELB as part of CloudFormation script itself? (so that we can manually re-attach them once we complete our tests).

Does Application Load Balancer work perhaps instead of Elastic Load Balancer in case ELBs are not sufficient?

Comment: CodeDeploy has hooks for this. Otherwise I would make your curl tests part of the ELB health check.

Comment: How would that help in pausing traffic? If the heath check passes - it would start pouring in traffic to the Instances

Comment: My point is if you want to run checks before allowing traffic, they should’ve part of your health check. We use a dedicated “health check” URL that is not the main site.

Comment: Interesting. How about is there a way in CFTs to NOT add the Instances to the ELB? Ie setup the autoscaling groups, create ELBs but prevent the attachment of the EC2 Instances on the ELB?

Comment: Autoscaling attaches to the LB not CloudFormation. You could use CodeDeploy hooks to prevent traffic. However, I have to say this smells like an XY problem.